# Keyboard&Win32api реализация получения точки координат курсора при нажатии ЛКМ (Python)

Tags: python, windows, winapi

Необходимо реализовать программу для получения точки координат курсора по нажатию ЛКМ. Плюс меня интересует, как разделить полученное значение на 2 разные переменный (x и y соответственно)
Ниже код, который я использовал ранее, для получения точки. Обращался к нему через меню в командной строке.

```
def GetPosCursor():
    win32api.GetCursorPos()
    print(win32api.GetCursorPos())
```